# Iphone Custom Mapkit Annotation Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I know how to change the pin to a custom image however, nobody says what the optimal image size needs to be for the custom pin image. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no "optimal" size for a custom annotation, the default pin is 32x29, but yours can be larger or smaller, depending on how you want it to look.